# Error calling drools REST API with data object contains a list

Tags: java, rest, drools, redhat-brms

I'm running into an issue where I'm trying to call drools using the REST API and as part of my layload I'm passing the main data object, plus a 2nd data object which will be my response object.  So, the idea is to have an empty response object in working memory that I can update.  My XML looks something like this:

```
<batch-execution lookup="defaultStatelessKieSession">
<insert out-identifier="RequestData" return-object="true" entry-point="DEFAULT">
    <com.test.package.RequestData>
        <fieldOne>ValueOne</fieldOne>
        <fieldTwo>ValueTwo</fieldTwo>
        <fieldThree>ValueThree</fieldThree>
    </com.test.package.RequestData>
</insert>
<insert out-identifier="ResponseData" return-object="false" entry-point="DEFAULT">
    <com.test.package.ResponseData>
        <ruleResults></ruleResults>
        <responseList></responseList>
    </com.test.package.ResponseData>
</insert>
<fire-all-rules />
<query name="rulesResponses" out-identifier="rulesResponses" />
</batch-execution>
```

Where, in my data object "responseList" is defined as:

```
private java.util.List<java.lang.String> responseList
```

Because it's defined as a list I get the following error trying to call the API:

```
<org.kie.server.api.model.ServiceResponse>
<type>FAILURE</type>
<msg>Error calling container TestContainer: No such field com.test.package.ResponseData.responseList
</org.kie.server.api.model.ServiceResponse>
```

So, my question is....

How do I properly represent my List attribute in the request payload so that it properly instantiates the response object instead of throwing this error?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is no longer an issue as we have gone a different route.

Marking question as answered.